Is there any way to handle Change Your Password prompt in Google Chrome using Selenium?
I am trying to automate an e-commerce website using Selenium-Java in Google Chrome where I do the login using username and password. Once the authentication is successful, the homepage opens. This Browser popup (Change Your Password - The password you just used was found in a data breach. Google Password Manager recommends changing your password now) is getting displayed in parallel, which I intend to suppress/handle so that it either doesn't show up at all or it gets closed. I looked at using ChromeOptions but I haven't been able to figure out the right argument to pass. Can anyone help, please?
enter image description here

Just a guess, have you tried to send keys? For example, enter.

This worked for me: https://issues.chromium.org/issues/42323769#comment23
final Map<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<>();
chromePrefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
chromePrefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
chromePrefs.put("profile.password_manager_leak_detection", false); // <======== This is the important one

final ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);

